# Java servlet not returning JSON Object to jquery ajax

Tags: java, json, ajax, servlets

i am building web using JSP with servlet. I code JSP to get data from Servlet using jquery ajax, which is returning JSON type. but when i tried to convert servlet response data into JSON and try to logging with console.log on ajax success, it's not returning JSON Object.

i'm using org.json.simple.JSONObject library for converting.

Here is my jquery code :

```
$.ajax({
    url : BASEPATH + 'load',
    type : 'get',
    success : function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error : function(response) {
        alert('error');
    }
});
```

Here is my servlet code :

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class SourceSystemServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    JSONObject resp = new JSONObject();

    public SourceSystemServlet()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        int code = 0;
        String message = "";

        code = 200;
        message = "Success";

        resp.put("code", code);
        resp.put("message", message);
        response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.getWriter().write(resp.toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        doPost(req, resp);
    }
}
```

i want to get data JSON object like this :

[image]

but what i've got is data string like this, so i can't use response as object to logging i.e console.log(response.code) :

[image]

i hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: er, all you put into your json is `code = 200;
        message = "Success";

        resp.put("code", code);
        resp.put("message", message);`  If you want more stuff put more stuff in

Comment: @ScaryWombat i want to console.log(response.code) but it show "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try `resp.toJSONString()` not `resp.toString()`.

Comment: still got the same :(

Comment: well... this works on my laptop, so I guess there might be something wrong with your jQuery? Anyway, you got the JSON string on your page, so you may try JSON.parse(response) to convert it to the object.

Comment: thanks charles, i've convert the response as you suggest in my jQuery without any change in servlet and it works. but i wonder how can it works on my other servlet like the 1st picture above without converting any response in my jQuery and use same code on servlet like my code above.

Comment: I don't know why the simple JSONObject didn't work on your computer. One suggestion might be helpful is to use gson library instead of simple JSONObject library.